# Unable to use scikit-learn package on M1 Mac Pro

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn, apple-m1

sklearn intallation steps on m1 mac:
brew install openblas
export OPENBLAS=$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew --prefix openblas)
export CFLAGS="-falign-functions=8 ${CFLAGS}"
pip install scikit-learn

While importing the sklearn module in python, I am receiving this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/xh/557wxmb52b9fpjjzhgkr335m0000gn/T/ipykernel_9797/2452514981.py in <module>
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      5 from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score, accuracy_score
      6 import scipy

/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,

/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>
     26 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     27 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 28 from .fixes import np_version, parse_version
     29 from ._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr
     30 from .validation import (

/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py in <module>
     18 import scipy.sparse as sp
     19 import scipy
---> 20 import scipy.stats
     21 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     22 import threadpoolctl

/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py in <module>
    439 """
    440 
--> 441 from .stats import *
    442 from .distributions import *
    443 from .morestats import *

/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in <module>
     35 from numpy import array, asarray, ma
     36 
---> 37 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
     38 from scipy.ndimage import measurements
     39 from scipy._lib._util import (check_random_state, MapWrapper,

/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py in <module>
     96 from .kdtree import *
     97 from .ckdtree import *
---> 98 from .qhull import *
     99 from ._spherical_voronoi import SphericalVoronoi
    100 from ._plotutils import *

ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/liblapack.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file)
```

I tried installing from conda, but there is not solution. Can anyone please help, how can i add the missing files

Comment: this may help https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19137

Comment: You can follow [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#macports-for-mac-osx) reference to install sclkit-learn in your Mac OS. In Conda, you can simply type `!pip install scikit_learn` to install scikit-learn.